# SSL Issue - Debugging ssl issue between laravel and Cloudfront

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to set up SSL certs for my laravel API so it can connect to my front end project. I'm hosting my server on aws EC2 so Ive been trying to use cloudfront and acm. I get a 502 error when trying to access my api routes using my DNS. In the error code cloud front sends a link and it tells me to use an open ssl command to determine if cloudfront can establish a connection. the command is

```
openssl s_client –connect domainname:443 –servername domainname
```

Once I add that with my domain name  I get this response.

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140306801927832:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:769:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 326 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1536682031
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Im not really sure where to go from here because this is my first time trying to set up ssl.

Comment: Does the domain name point to cloudfront or to the EC2 instance? If you are trying to use an ACM SSL certificate, then the EC2 instance does not have an SSL certificate, only CloudFront has it. The domain name should be pointing to cloudfront, where the SSL certificate is installed, and cloudfront should NOT be trying to connect to the EC2 instance via SSL.

Comment: The domain name points to cloudfront. 
cloudfront points to the ec2 instance via its origin and cloudfronts CNAMEs is set to my domain name (which I put in the browser)

Comment: @JermayneWilliams the point of using `openssl s_client` is to test against your origin, so `domainname` needs to be the value you're using as the Origin Domain Name in CloudFront.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot if I swap my domain name for my origin (in place of both domain names) I get the same error.

Comment: You may be using an older version of openssl.  Try adding the `-tls1` or `-no_ssl3` option.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot so the response should be `openssl s_client –connect domainname:443 –servername domainname -no_ssl3` or `openssl s_client –connect domainname:443 –servername domainname -tls1`

Comment: Either of those should work.  Also, put `true` and a pipe `|` before the command -- it won't change the result but will close the input pipe so that the connection will not hang until the server disconnects you.  `true | openssl s_client -connect www.sqlbot.net:443 -servername www.sqlbot.net -no_ssl3` works for me.  You are welcome to test against my server if you like, for comparison.